# Simple console output formatting

Tags: c#

There is my program.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double weeklySales = 0, grossPay = 0, fedTax = 0, socSecurity = 0, retirement = 0, totDeductions = 0, takeHomePay = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total for sales for the week.");
        weeklySales = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        grossPay = weeklySales * .07;
        fedTax = grossPay * .18;
        socSecurity = grossPay * .06;
        retirement = grossPay * .1;
        totDeductions = fedTax + socSecurity + retirement;
        takeHomePay = grossPay - totDeductions;

        Console.WriteLine("Your total sales for the week were $ ", weeklySales);
        Console.WriteLine("Your gross pay for the week was $ ", grossPay);
        Console.WriteLine("Your Federal Taxes for the week were $ ", fedTax);
        Console.WriteLine("You were deducted $ ", socSecurity, " for social security.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your retirement contribution was $ ", retirement);
        Console.WriteLine("The total amount of of deductions were $ ", totDeductions);
        Console.WriteLine("Your take home pay for the week is $ ", takeHomePay);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The problem is an incorrect output.

```
Please enter your total for sales for the week.
 123
 Your total sales for the week were $
 Your gross pay for the week was $
 Your Federal Taxes for the week were $
 You were deducted $
 Your retirement contribution was $
 The total amount of of deductions were $
 Your take home pay for the week is $
```

I need to include calculated values to output.
How can I do this?

Comment: well, james, what about 'explaining' the problem? well, it's great you got a program, but, what you want SO users to do with it? are you facing some 'problem', if yes, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, this line won't work:

```
Console.WriteLine("You were deducted ${0}", socSecurity, " for social security.");
```

It will need to be:

```
Console.WriteLine("You were deducted ${0} for social security.", socSecurity);
```

The other alternative is to use string concatenation:

```
Console.WriteLine("You were deducted $" + socSecurity + " for social security.");
```

Comment: Ah.  I understand! the {0} tells it to reference the variable.

Comment: The {0} tells it to reference the _first_ variable.  You could also do `Console.WriteLine("You were deducted ${0} for {1}.", amount, reason);`

Comment: @JamesPurdon Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you would just have to replace `$` with `{0}` to show the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

In the current code, you're not specifying where the values should be entered into the string outputs. You can change them as follows and receive the output that you're looking for:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Your total sales for the week were ${0}", weeklySales);
        Console.WriteLine("Your gross pay for the week was ${0}", grossPay);
        Console.WriteLine("Your Federal Taxes for the week were ${0}", fedTax);
        Console.WriteLine("You were deducted ${0} for social security.", socSecurity);
        Console.WriteLine("Your retirement contribution was ${0}", retirement);
        Console.WriteLine("The total amount of of deductions were ${0}", totDeductions);
        Console.WriteLine("Your take home pay for the week is ${0}", takeHomePay);
```